# Keeping track of reports printed in SQL database

Tags: sql-server, view, records

I have a MS SQL database that I am working on, within this database I have a view that queries information to be printed on a INITIAL letter (sent one time). My idea is to have a table that stores the incident number of the record for this letter and the date it was printed so that I can cross reference this table when the view runs so as to not get any incidents that have already been printed.

In your opinion is this the best method or is there another method that should be done?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved for now. Created a procedure to call the view (which checked against the audit table) and forcing the developers to add the letter record to the audit table once the letter is printed

Answer (score 0):

You could use a stored procedure to return the view data, and within that procedure capture the user data and populate the "audit" table.

Comment: I did consider this, however, the client may not want to print all the letters even though the letters are ready. If the procedure automatically added to the "audit" table the letter will be inaccesible next time. So couldn't do this.